# download / export google drive sheet in my working directory

Tags: javascript, php, google-drive-api

I want to access the google drive sheet in csv format to my working directory. I tried by google quickstart guide, but didn't get any solution.

Comment: Have you read https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads?

Comment: yes I has readed the doc. but I am very confused about the process. Can you please suggest me the step by step process to do this.

Comment: @techie I think they provide a pretty clear documentation: `$fileId = '1ZdR3L3qP4Bkq8noWLJHSr_iBau0DNT4Kli4SxNc2YEo';
$response = $driveService->files->export($fileId, 'application/pdf', array(
  'alt' => 'media' ));
$content = $response->getBody()->getContents();` (where you need to use content type `text/csv`). Please try this first and post your problem after trying. So that we can help you more specifically.

Comment: I tried out the given code with my google project. It was not working properly. so now I had created a new project in google console and I got the error while running quickstart.php:   Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: { "error": "unauthorized_client", "error_description": "Unauthorized" } in C:\xampp\htdocs\newsheet\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php:118

Answer (score 0):

If you meant to say you wanted to export the file as CSV and download it to your computer, use [Files.export](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/export) GET request:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id={GOOGLE_SPREADHSHEET_ID}&exportFormat=csv&mimeType=text/csv
```

I already added the `mimeType=text/csv` for you so it saves as .csv file. Just place your Google `SpreadsheetID` and run it on your browser.

Comment: yes the link is working but I am confused about the file structure will you please let me know. Where I can use the above given code

Comment: I think one way of doing it is to open a browser window in Javascript using window.open(' URL_HERE','text/csv');